# Duties on 2 laptops while travelling to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, india

I am an Indian living in Australia as permanent resident. I intend to carry 2 laptops to India while on an official trip. 1 laptop is company one and another is personal. I am carrying personal one for getting it repaired in India.

Can I do this without the need to pay any duties?

Comment: I bring two laptops with me all the time. As far as now, they didn't care.

Comment: This duplicate does not apply because the items are only being temporarily imported, and will not remain in the country.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this, provided you will be exporting the laptops from India within a certain time.

The legal procedure is an ATA Carnet (pronounced kar-nay) Rules for acceptance differ, so you will need to check the requirements for India

http://www.atacarnet.in/

The carnet would be issued to you in Australia

https://www.austrade.gov.au/contact/faqs/what-is-an-ata-carnet-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-take-to-send-goods-overseas-temporarily